# Where is python.exe in a Windows tarball installation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After installing Python 3.5.6 using a tarball (.gz file), I would like to run

`C:\path\to\desired\venv\directory>c:\path\to\python\installation\Python-3.5.6\python -m venv venv`

However, my Python-3.5.6 directory doesn't seem to include the necessary `python.exe`. After extracting Python from a tarball on Windows, what extra steps are required to produce the `python` executable?

---

**Note:** I already have Python 3.6 installed as the default.

Comment: What does `dir C:\ ` output?

Comment: The output is too lengthy to paste here. Can you be more specific about what you're looking for?

Comment: Can't this be resolved by doing a simple file search within your Python-3.5.6 for 'python.exe', also my guess is it must be sitting in the Scripts folder

Comment: I want to make sure that your `C:` drive actually contains a folder called `Python-3.5.6`. Also I think the capital C matters

Comment: @MattMessersmith I used "..." but the actual location is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python-3.5.6. I don't think the capital C matters, esp. since the docs use lowercase.

Comment: @SomeGuy A file search only comes up with python_exe.rc. I looked for a Scripts folder too, but there isn't one immediately under Python-3.5.6 as expected. Only within Lib/venv, Mac/BuildScript, and Tools.

Comment: Have you tried using `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python-3.5.6\python`? Idk where you're getting `C:\...\Python-3.5.6`. Those paths are NOT the same AFAIK unless you've got some goofy shell aliasing going on.

Comment: Also, `python` is probably already on your PATH. Have you tried `python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv`? (straight from the docs)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That is what I tried; I just tried to shorten things with "..." when describing the situation. I've edited the question now.

Comment: Using `python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv` works, but uses the default 3.6 installation. I need 3.5.

Comment: Just verified that if I use Python 3.5.4, the last 3.5 release that included a .exe installer, my method works. I could stop here with 3.5.4, but I'd like to know why `python.exe` doesn't show up in my 3.5.6 tarball-extracted installation.

Comment: @NathanielJones Oh I see about the "..." thing. I have no idea why `python.exe` isn't in your tarball. I think it should be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a "tarball installation". You downloaded the source code and extracted it manually into somewhere you shouldn't. This is roughly analogous to attempting to live in the blueprints of a house.

If for some reason you are determined to use 3.5.6, you will have to find an actual installer somewhere (there is no official one), or you will have to build it yourself. From `PCbuild/readme.txt`:

> ### Quick Start Guide
>
> 1. Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, any edition.
> 2. Install Subversion, and make sure 'svn.exe' is on your PATH.
> 3. Run "build.bat -e" to build Python in 32-bit Release configuration.
> 4. (Optional, but recommended) Run the test suite with "rt.bat -q".

For more complete build instructions, see [`PCbuild/readme.txt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.6/PCbuild/readme.txt).

Comment: I've tried following these instructions and ran into, `C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Python\Python-3.5.6\PCbuild\pythoncore.vcxproj(42,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\
Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the
file exists on disk.`. At this point, I'm just going to go with Python 3.5.4 and call it good.